# new to javascript, how do i change color of --> document.write(schedule[row]['title']); to red?

Tags: javascript, colors

I am pretty new to javascript and i cannot figure out how to change the color of the first "document.write" in my for/in loop? 
--> document.write(schedule[row]['title']); <--

```
var schedule = [], row, col;

var TECH276 = { title : "JavaScript Fundamentals",
                credits : 3,
                section : 1,
                days : "Thursday",
                time : "6:30 p.m. - 9:25 p.m.",
                semester : "Spring 2019",
                fascinating : true
            };

var TECH277 = { title : "Advanced Javascript",
                credits : 3,
                section : 1,
                days : "Thursday",
                time : "6:30 p.m. - 9:05 p.m.",
                semester : "Fall 2019",
                fascinating : true
            };

schedule[0] = TECH276;
schedule[1] = TECH277;

for (row in schedule) {
    document.write(schedule[row]['title']);
    document.write("<br />");
    for (col in schedule[row]) {
        document.write('The property ' + "<i>" + col + "</i>" + ' = <b>'+ schedule[row][col] + "</b>&nbsp; &nbsp; <br>");
    }
    document.write("<br />");
}
```

Comment: how would you do it in HTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just wrap it in a `span` and style it:

```js
var schedule = [],
  row, col;

var TECH276 = {
  title: "JavaScript Fundamentals",
  credits: 3,
  section: 1,
  days: "Thursday",
  time: "6:30 p.m. - 9:25 p.m.",
  semester: "Spring 2019",
  fascinating: true
};

var TECH277 = {
  title: "Advanced Javascript",
  credits: 3,
  section: 1,
  days: "Thursday",
  time: "6:30 p.m. - 9:05 p.m.",
  semester: "Fall 2019",
  fascinating: true
};

schedule[0] = TECH276;
schedule[1] = TECH277;

for (row in schedule) {
  document.write('<span style="color:red">' + schedule[row]['title'] + '</span>');
  document.write("<br />");
  for (col in schedule[row]) {
    document.write('The property ' + "<i>" + col + "</i>" + ' = <b>' + schedule[row][col] + "</b>&nbsp; &nbsp; <br>");
  }
  document.write("<br />");
}
```

Comment: Duh! Forgot span was a thing... I was trying to use a div tag forgetting the concatenation, much appreciated